# Any open source data analysis software around?

Tags: software-recommendation

Are the any apps for analysing data like SPSS, Minitab etc in Windows for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I reccomend R for data analysis and visualization.

> R is an open source programming
>   language and software environment for
>   statistical computing and graphics. It
>   is an implementation of the S
>   programming language combined with
>   lexical scoping semantics inspired by
>   Scheme. R was created by Ross Ihaka
>   and Robert Gentleman and is now
>   developed by the R Development Core
>   Team. It is easily extended through a
>   packaging system on CRAN. Further
>   information on R can be found on the
>   project website www.r-project.org

Have a look at these links =

http://www.r-project.org/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/

Comment: Don't forget the recently-released [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.org/). They provide deb files for Ubuntu somewhere on the site.

Answer (score 3):

If you are after something like SPSS in particular, you could try [GNU PSPP](http://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/), which is packaged in Ubuntu.  It strives to remain compatible with the SPSS command language and data formats, but does not support all SPSS commands.

If it is not suitable for what you want to do, I would suggest looking at R as the other answers have suggested.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about "data mining" software then there is a useful wikipedia entry that could help is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_and_open_source_software_packages#Data_mining)

An opensource alternative to SPSS could be the [r-project](http://www.r-project.org/)

Minitab works under [wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=213) to run on Ubuntu and I know you can get a good student deal from college (assuming of course that you are a student!)